# In AngularJS how do you load a page with an element hidden?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In AngularJS how do you ensure an HTML element starts in a hidden state when loading the page?

On my page there is an initial delay while the controller is created where the element can be seen on the screen before it disappears.

I've tried combining these attributes in various ways:

```
<li 
    data-ng-show
    data-ng-if
    data-ng-cloak
    class="ng-hide"
```

but the element always displays for half a second on the screen before vanishing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to manage loading of a page is to use "resolve" in the route: it will give access to your controller and partial only when the asynchronous call returns.

see resolve in this documentation:

```
 https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider
```

For your question, if you still need ng-show, it should work if you init your variables to false.

Edit: sorry, ng-show seem actually to have problem on angular bootstrapping.

Comment: Resolve looks like the way to go. Wish I'd known about this earlier, now I have change our code a bit. Here's a more instructive link: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/20/using-resolve-in-angularjs-routes.aspx. (Also, starting with my variables set to false doesn't work.)

Comment: Please check my answer below, I think it resume what you can do

Answer (score 1):

There are several way to do this.

It's only when the ng-app is triggered that AngularJS bootstraps.
Bootstrapping can be done manualy at some point of time.

```
angular.module('appName', []);

angular.element(document).ready(function(){
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['appName']);
});
```

Another method is to use `ng-cloak`. This allows you to display a portion of a page only when AngularJS has bootstrapped.

Set a `class="ng-cloak"` in your portion you wan't to hide before AngularJS is bootstrapped.
Angular include this class and just applies a `display : none !important` to it.
Once the app is bootstrapped, angular look for those elements and display them.

Notice, it is good practice to make `resolves` or declare (what you can declare) in your config method

Answer (score 1):

For `ng-Cloak` to work , make sure you have the appropriate CSS rule as well:

```
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
  display: none !important;
}
```

See here:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Answer (score 0):

Give them a css class that sets them to `display: none` initially. The `ng-show`/`ng-hide`/`ng-if` should override them as required when Angular finally kicks in. It's all visible at the start as the page has finished rendering the DOM but Angular has yet to initialise.

Comment: This didn't work for me. The element stays hidden forever.

Comment: @Richard Hmm, sorry about that. It's working for us. We must be using a different method of showing/hiding.